# How to skip Shipping and Payment method in checkout (magento 1.9)

Tags: checkout, shipping, billing

I need to skip the Shipping and Payment method steps in checkout.

This, because a lot of products need customising and checking before shipping them. 
So what we do is check the list (with the client) and contact/inform them. The actual order will be processed through another system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code for skip shipping Address and billing Address from checkout steps :

First override following files(i.e. in local directory) rather than changing the core:

```
1) app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Onepage.php
2) app/code/core/mage/checkout/controller/Onepagecontrollers.php
3) app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php
4) app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml
5) app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php
```

Once done follow the below steps:

Step 1: app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php

Change the line:

```
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
```

In Magento 1.7+ you will find $stepCodes in for each just replace with below code 
with:

```
$stepCodes = array('shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
```

**Step 2: app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controller/Onepagecontrollers.php**

Change the line:

```
protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
'payment-method' => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
'shpping-method' => '_getShippingMeghtoHtml',
'review' => '_getReviewHtml',
);
```

with:

```
protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
'payment-method' => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
'review' => '_getReviewHtml',
);
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I tried but I have a few questions.

I assume the first dir must be app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php 
instead of
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Onepage.php

And the 5th directory (app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php) is the same as the 3rd. Can I just skip that one or does it have to be another directory?

Also, I don't see this line:
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
but this one:
$stepCodes = array_diff($stepCodes, array('login'));
Can I just go ahead and change this line?

Comment: Yes, Lidacha inside block

Comment: I resolved this by using the extension "Reduced Checkout Free", which works like a charm.